# Bootstrap mobile navbar is open on load and won't toggle

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hey guys I am a little confused to why my mobile navbar is open on page load and won't toggle.  I have copied the code from my other mobile navbar that I made however I am obviously missing.

Just so you know the navbar only displays for small devices as the navbar for large devices is separate.

#### [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/608/)

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default nav-links navbar-fixed-top hidden-md hidden-lg">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="visible-sm visible-xs navbar-toggle" type="button"
                data-target="#i-want-this-to-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" >
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button>
        <a class="mini-navbar navbar-brand" href="/">
            <img src="media/img/nav-logo.png" alt="Driven Car Sales Logo"
                 class="img-rounded logo-nav mini-navbar" />
        </a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Join us</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    About<strong class="caret"></strong>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li> <a href "#">The Team</a></li>
                    <li> <a href "#">Our Partners</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">How To Find Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```css
.mini-navbar {
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
    /*body {display: none;}*/
    .navbar-nav > li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none;
    }
    .nav.navbar-nav {
        clear: both;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 0 0 -15px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
        border: none;
    }

    .navbar-nav > li:last-child {
        border: none;
    }
    .navbar-default {

    }
}
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: What exactly did you mean by *"won't toggle"*? `hide/show`? If so, Are you using any css only trick to toggle it? if not, does bootstrap js does that part? if not, where is the js..?

Comment: It's Bootstrap I have added the Bootstrap components however I mustn't have added one of the CSS classes I am just unsure which one.

Comment: Just to be sure, did you add the bootstrap js?

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your toggle button and navbar-brand anchor inside a navbar header:

```
<div class="navbar-header"><!-- --></div>
```

You need to wrap your list of navbar-nav menu items inside of a navbar collapse section:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse"><!-- --></div>
```

Most importantly, the `data-target` used for toggling takes a CSS selector of the section you want to toggle.  You currently have:

```
<button data-target="#i-want-this-to-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" >
```

But there is nothing that matches the selector `#i-want-this-to-collapse`, namely, something with that ID.  So add one to your navbar-collapse:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="i-want-this-to-collapse">
```

#### [Here's a working demo in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/609/)

Check the fiddle for the full code.

In the future, I'd start with an example from the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) and work your way toward your own solution so you can find out where you've broken it along the way.  Pause, and take a couple steps back to see if it makes sense.  If not, ask *that* question because it's likely to be a much better question i.e. why does *x* not work? I thought it would do *y*.

Comment: I tried implementing what you have told me into my site however it doesn't function the way it does in JSFiddle I'm unsure what is causing it, if you look here: http://www.dealerbyte.co.uk/

You can see when it collapses it doesn't function in the way that the JSFiddle example does :(

Comment: @NickM, Please upvote and accept answers you find helpful, regardless of whether or not you are able to successfully implement them on your site.  If you are still having trouble, simplify your own code until you have identified the issue and then ask a *specific* question about that, with a working external demo.  **See also**: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1366033)

Answer (score 1):

there is some problem with your code try following error free working code:

```
   <!-- Static navbar -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Join us</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li> <a href "#">The Team</a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href "#">Our Partners</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">How To Find Us</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
  </li>
</ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/7046/)

Comment: What was wrong with my code? I tried adding your nav code however it won't work when it's implemented into my site it covers the whole viewport. What could I add to my current code to make that toggle?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. In addition to making a div with id "i-want-this-to-collapse" there are some required classes for this div. Which are "collapse" and "navbar-collapse". So you basically have to write :

```html
   <div id="i-want-this-to-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right visible-xs-block">
          <li>...</li>
          <li>...</li>
            
     </ul>
    </div>
```